# TTK error in programms with LTK

Tags: common-lisp, ttk, ltk

After upgrade of the system from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 11.04, have a problem with LTK.
Programs with LTK load successful, but after loading the function I had an error "Can't find TTK package". As I know TTK is the part of Tk libraries. But Tcl\Tk is installed and configured.

Comment: Why don't you set the ltk debug variable and see what the actual error is? If you can't figure it out, can you edit the error message into the question?

Comment: @Paul. Here is the message from slime terminal: "Tcl\Tk error: invalid command name "ttk:frame" [Condition of type LTK:TK-ERROR]"

Comment: Fire up wish and replicate the commands in Wish as a path to determining the error.   I also suggest editing your question with the specific LTK code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Tk 8.5 in order to have Ttk (or a special development package with a different name — Tile — with Tk 8.4, but that's not recommended). You also need to make sure that the name used when invoking things uses a double-colon (`ttk::frame`) because that's the namespace separator; single colon is just an unusual part of a normal command name. (I don't know if that was caused by your transcription of the error message though.)

Answer (score 0):

The current releases of LTk require wish8.5 or above. Wish is invoked via the command in `*wish-pathname*`. So make either sure that `wish` which is the default, is in your path and points to version 8.5 or above (some systems only install it as wish8.5). Alternatively, you can change the content of `*wish-pathname*` to the name of the correct wish executable.